# VichUploaderBundle in Symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I hope you can help me because i'm searching and i'm lost :(

I'm trying to upload image in my symfony 6 project with VichUploaderBundle.

I used the doc : https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/usage.md#step-1-configure-an-upload-mapping

But i have this error :

> The class "App\Entity\Client" is not uploadable. If you use annotations to configure VichUploaderBundle, you probably just forgot to add `@Vich\Uploadable` on top of your entity. If you don't use annotations, check that the configuration files are in the right place. In both cases, clearing the cache can also solve the issue.

My vich_uploader.yaml :

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm


    mappings:
       clients_logo:
           uri_prefix: '%client_logo%'
           upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public%client_logo%'
           namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\SmartUniqueNamer
```

My Client Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\ClientRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ClientRepository::class)]
#[Vich\Uploadable]
class Client
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $numero_client;

    /**
    * Some fields
    */

    /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     */
    #[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: 'clients_logo', fileNameProperty: 'logo')]
    private ?File $imageFile = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private $logo;


    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime', nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->applis = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLogo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->logo;
    }

    public function setLogo(?string $logo): self
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile|null $imageFile
     */
    public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile = null): void
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

        if (null !== $imageFile) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    public function getImageFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function getBddClient(): ?BaseClient
    {
        return $this->bdd_client;
    }

    public function setBddClient(?BaseClient $bdd_client): self
    {
        $this->bdd_client = $bdd_client;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Applis>
     */
    public function getApplis(): Collection
    {
        return $this->applis;
    }

    public function addAppli(Applis $appli): self
    {
        if (!$this->applis->contains($appli)) {
            $this->applis[] = $appli;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAppli(Applis $appli): self
    {
        $this->applis->removeElement($appli);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdateAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdateAt(): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My FormType :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Client;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
            ])
            //Some add fields
            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ]);

        //Indispensable pour faire fonctionner le select du formulaire sinon erreur 500
        $builder->get('type_contrat')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($typeContratArray) {
                    // transform the array to a string
                    return count($typeContratArray) ? $typeContratArray[0] : null;
                },
                function ($typeContratString) {
                    // transform the string back to an array
                    return [$typeContratString];
                }
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Client::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my form twig :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    {{ form_row(form.imageFile, { 
        label: 'Logo',
        'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}
    }) }}
</div>
```

Anybody can explain what's going on ? :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you are using Php 8+ configure the bundle to use **attributes** instead of **annotations**

```
vich_uploader:
    metadata:
        type: attribute
```

ref [docs](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/configuration_reference.md#configuration-reference)

**Edit 21 Nov 2022:** As of [v2](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/releases/tag/2.0.0) of the bundle, `attribute` is the default value.

Comment: Oh dude, thanks so much ! It's Ok now ! I was so tired that I didn't saw this line in the doc 